# Practical purposes of Antique Coins

Tags: resident-evil-7

What do the Antique Coins unlock in Resident Evil 7?

They're found throughout the game in various places and allegedly there are 18 of them to unlock various things in the game but I haven't found what they unlock or how to unlock what the coins are supposed to allegedly unlock.

Comment: Perhaps accept an answer if your question has been answered?

Answer (score 3):

The antique coins can be used to purchase items locked in birdcages (see picture) in the [trailer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkaZf.jpg) (found when you first exit the house) saving area. The coins are dispensed one by one.
Prices:

- Steroids - 3 Antique Coins
- Stabilizer - 5 Antique Coins
- .44 Magnum - 9 Antique Coins

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Several things to add to @user598527 answer:

> You actually can't buy all items before point-of-no-return, as several coins can be found only after this point-of-no-return. Items you didn't bought will appear again closer to end of the game.

Also, there are 33 coins on Madhouse difficulty. Aside of 3 common items, which can be found in trailer, there are next items, which can be found in main hall:

- Iron Defense Coin - 7 coins
- Assault Coin - 8 coins
- Scorpio Key - 3 coins

As you can note, not all items can be purchased within one run, since total cost is 35 coins, while only 33 can be found on Madhouse (+1 from demo).

Comment: Is the main hall store only available on Madhouse difficulty?

Comment: @user598527 yes.